# Multi Subdomain - Muti Site with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5, multiple-domains

I would like to create a site that has multiple subdomains, each subdomain is an integral independent Laravel application.
There is only one folder for the site.

**Demontration**

www.example.com (the main website)
blog.example.com (An independent blog)
music.example.com (Application of Independent Music)

I try to do this

```
Route::group(['domain' => 'dcolsay.dev'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'blog.dcoslay.dev'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
        return view('blog::index');
    });
});
```

I use [PingPong - Module](https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules)
https://github.com/pingpong-labs/modules

The first route work but the second i have this error

**NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:**

Comment: ...and?? What code have you tried? Please share.

Comment: `Route::group(['domain' => 'dcolsay.dev'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
});
Route::group(['domain' => 'blog.dcoslay.com'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function() {
    return view('blog::index');
});
});`

Comment: ...and what's the problem? Explain the problem you're running into. And always include code to avoid getting down votes - but more importantly, find a solution to your problem.

Comment: What happens when you replace `return view('blog::index');` with `return "test";` and you then visit the URL?

Comment: are you using nginx? if yes then you need to configure it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the index.php from the folder of `resources > blog` then 
you have to use the view as `"return view('blog.index');"` instead of `"return view('blog::index');"`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Hyn's package : https://github.com/hyn/multi-tenant

I used it for my server with one laravel application for all projects hosted.
Every domain has it own diretory such as views, routes, translations, packages etc...

You also use https://github.com/hyn/management-interface to create dashboard to manage your hostnames.

Comment: Please note that this answer is provided based on an older version of hyn/multi-tenant. The management interface has become deprecated and was removed. Please see https://laravel-tenancy.com for the latest information on this package.